# Java insert into array after converted to list

Tags: java, java-collections-api

```
        String[] arr = { "Java", "Champ", "." };
        List<String> list = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(arr);  // line 1
        arr[2] = ".com"; // line 2
        for (String word : list) {
            System.out.print(word);
        }
```

How this results output as `JavaChamp.com` even it is converted into List in line 1 and modified in line 2

Comment: Your `(List<String>)` cast should not be needed.

Answer (score 7):

[`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) doesn't copy the array into a list - it creates a *view* onto the array. Any change you make via the list affects the array, and vice versa. That's why you can't add to (or remove from) the list returned by `Arrays.asList` - because the array itself can't change size.

The documentation makes this clear in one direction:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

... but it works both ways, because the list just has no dedicated backing storage. It really is just backed by the array.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

From the JavaDoc for [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

This means your `List<String>` is still backed by the array. So if you change the array, you change what is in the list.

**Edit** and for extra fun, you can do the same in reverse:

```
String[] arr = { "Java", "Champ", "." };
List<String> list = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(arr);  // line 1
arr[2] = ".com"; // line 2
list.set(0, "Foo"); // Array is now {"Foo", "Champ", ".com"};
```

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` returns a "list view" of the array you pass in. It doesn't copy the array. `list.get(1)`, for example, just delegates to `arr[1]`. So as you continue to change the array elements, you continue to implicitly change the list elements.